# Using tuple of integers as a key in python not working

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where I store a tuple (x,y) as the key

However, when I place the following condition it returns true even though the tuple is already in the dictionary.

```
            if (virtual_box_i, virtual_box_j) not in self.visitid_indices:
                break
```

I am sure the tuple is there as I can see it in self.visitid_indices when debugging as below:

[image]

What could be I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure what the image is about, but it's hardly readable, and images containing code or (text) output are strongly discouraged, as these are not searchable or readable by screen readers.

Comment: How do you know that the condition is evaluated as "true"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because it's getting inside the if condition

Comment: @Evert You were right. After casting the indices to python int things worked. It's strange that NumPy int type is not working in this case

Comment: @Evert Please put your answer separately to upvote it

Comment: Are you using a very old version of numpy? I'm pretty sure that `np.int64` is supposed to has the same as `int` (or, in 2.x, as `long`), and therefore `np.int64(7) in {7}` should work, in every version going back to before it was numpy—but there was a bug a few years ago (somewhere around the time Python 3.3 came out maybe?) that broke that temporarily.

Comment: Can you print out `(np.int64(2), np.int64(7)) in {(2,7)}`? If False, please list your platform, Python version, and numpy version, and how you installed them. Because if you have either a very old numpy version, or a broken build of numpy, you probably want to fix that, rather than working around this particular symptom.

Comment: @abarnert I am using NumPy 1.13.0 and Python 2.7.12 with anaconda 4.1.1

Comment: I think I found what I was remembering: [gh-3800](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3800), [gh-3793](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3793), or one of the related issues mentioned in those two. But they were fixed in 1.9 and backported as far as 1.7, so… that can't be your issue if you're on 1.13.

Comment: @abarnert The opened issues were for python3 while I am using python2.7 on a 64 bit platform. I guess it's a hashing problem too.

Comment: @HishamRagheb The second sentence of the first issue is "Same for long long for wich the numpy hash function is not correct with python 2.7 on i386." And Python 2 is discussed multiple further times across the linked issues. So why do you think it's for Python 3 only?

Comment: @HishamRagheb At any rate, have you actually done the test I asked you to do? Instead of just guessing, test it. And edit that (together with all the version information) into your question.

Comment: @abarnert I promise to do that later. Unfortunately, I am in the middle of a project and have no time for extensive testing. But I will update the question once I get a strong evident test case

Answer (score 0):

Your image appears to state `virtual_box_i/j` are `int64`, which may be indicative of a NumPy type. NumPy type integers are (unfortunately or not) the same as normal integers. Try using

```
(int(virtual_box_i), int(virtual_box_j))
```

instead, to explicitly convert the (supposed) NumPy integers to standard Python integers.

---

Note that, with Python 2.7.13 and NumPy 1.13.1, I can't actually reproduce the issue:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Feb  1 2017, 17:19:54) 
[GCC 5.4.1 20160904] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {(1, 2L): 'test'}
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2L
>>> (x, y) in d
True
>>> (x, 2) in d
True
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.int64(1)
>>> b = np.int64(2)
>>> (a, b) in d
True
>>> np.__version__
'1.13.1'
```

As mentioned in the comments, comparisons with `np.int64` evaluate properly even when the key consists of ints or longs.

Comment: why do you think that testing a dict with single key is a valid test case?

Comment: @HishamRagheb If the key is not in the dict, it would return `False`. So if ints, longs and int64 don't match up, the return value should be `False.`